# How integrate Mocha test file with Webpack process?

Tags: javascript, mocha.js

I have a JS class I would like to write tests for. I got Mocha installed. Created a file `test.js` in project root. I can now run tests within that like this

```
var assert = require('assert');

describe('Arithmetic', function() {
    describe('Plus', function() {
        it('1 + 1 equals 2', function() {
        assert.equal(1+1, 2);
        });
    });
});
```

All good! The thing I am unsure of is how to test my file as it includes a lot of ES6 things. For example imports like

```
import someDependency from 'resources/assets/js/someDependencyToMyClass';
```

How do I make it so mocha knows of my package.json/webpack process? Or should I just test the transpiled versions of my code?

---

I tried to setup a test class myself and run with Node but then I am bypassing all the Babel stuff so it won't work. I also thought about making a test page in addition to my SPA (React) but I rather not clutter the actual code. How would you do this?

Also, here is my projects package.json.

```
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "npm run development",
        "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "watch": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --watch --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
        "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "prod": "npm run production",
        "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "axios": "^0.17",
        "babel-preset-react": "^6.23.0",
        "cross-env": "^5.1",
        "jquery": "^3.2",
        "laravel-mix": "^1.0",
        "lodash": "^4.17.4",
        "mocha": "^5.0.0",
        "react": "^15.4.2",
        "react-dom": "^15.4.2",
        "testing": "^1.1.1"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "bootstrap": "^4.0.0",
        "popper.js": "^1.12.9",
        "react-redux": "^5.0.6",
        "redux": "^3.7.2"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to pull in `mocha-webpack` (https://github.com/zinserjan/mocha-webpack) in order to precompile your code according to your webpack config.
Then you can simply create a test script in your `package.json` pointing to your webpack config like so:

`"scripts": {
    "test": "mocha-webpack --webpack-config=webpack.config.js tests/*.js"
}`.

Running `npm test` will then precompile your code properly. Hopefully it points you in the right direction.